# Binding http GET response with isolate scopes in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As the title implies, I'm trying to get some data from a database via an http get request and then display it in a list of divs with ngRepeat. I need to call a function on each repeated item of ngRepeat so that the request can use the object (the "room" in "room in rooms") as a url parameter. The issue, I think, is that because I have isolated the scope of the function, the response from the http request (count) seems to be out of reach of the function. How can I make it so I can display the response in the view {{count}} while keeping it within it's own isolated scope, with the function?

**http**

```
<div ng-repeat="room in rooms">
            <div>{{room}}</div><br>
            <div plant attrcount="plantCount(room)"></div>
</div>
```

**server.js**

```
MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI, function(err, db) {
    var plantList = db.collection("plantList");

app.get('/getrooms', function(req, res) {
       plantList
           .distinct("room", function(err, docs) {
           res.json(docs);
       });
    });

app.get('/getplantsbyroom/:room', function(req, res) {
        var roomReq = req.params.room;
        plantList.count({"room":roomReq}, function(err, count) {
            res.json(count);
        });
    });

});
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get('/getrooms').success(function (response) {
            $scope.rooms = response;
        });

$scope.plantCount = function(room) {
        var url = '/getplantsbyroom/' + room;
        $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
            $scope.count = response;
        })
    }
});

angular.module('myApp').directive("plant", function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            attrcount:"&"
        },
        template: '<p ng-init="attrcount(room)">{{count}}</p>' //doesn't display count
    }
});
```

Comment: Why bother with the directive at all?

Comment: Are you getting rooms through a $http request? something like `$scope.rooms = $http.get()`?

Comment: Because every time I call the plantCount() function I change all count variables of the repeated items to the same thing. So I need to isolate them so each repeated item is unique. It might help to see my node/express code so I'll post that as well.

Comment: @Austin, yep that is correct. I just included that bit above. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off getting all your data together before using it in the controller instead of trying to load it in ng-reapeat. Angular's [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service can help you join multiple promisses together with [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).To keep things clean you can create your own service to manage your requests and just inject it into your controller.

```
controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, RoomService) {
  RoomService.listRooms().then(function(rooms) {
    $scope.rooms = rooms;
  });
}).service("RoomService", function($http, $q) {
  var roomService = {};
  roomService.listRooms = function() {
    return $http.get("rooms").then(function(rooms) {
      return $q.all(rooms.map(roomService.getPlantCount));
    });
  }
  roomService.getPlantCount = function(room) {
    return $http.get('/getplantsbyroom/' + room).then(function(plantCount) {
      return {
        room: room,
        plantCount: plantCount
      };
    });
  }
  return roomService;
})
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, RoomService) {
  RoomService.listRooms().then(function(rooms) {
    $scope.rooms = rooms;
  });
}).service("RoomService", function($httpMock, $q) {
  var roomService = {};
  roomService.listRooms = function() {
    return $httpMock.get("rooms").then(function(rooms) {
      return $q.all(rooms.map(roomService.getPlantCount));
    });
  }
  roomService.getPlantCount = function(room) {
    return $httpMock.get('/getplantsbyroom/' + room).then(function(plantCount) {
      return {
        room: room,
        plantCount: plantCount
      };
    });
  }
  return roomService;
}).service("$httpMock", function($q) {
  var $httpMock = {};
  $httpMock.get = function(url) {
    return (url === "rooms") ?
      $httpMock.mockRooms() : $httpMock.mockPlantCount(url);
  }

  $httpMock.mockRooms = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(["lorem", "ipsum"]);
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  $httpMock.mockPlantCount = function(url) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (url === "/getplantsbyroom/lorem") {
      deferred.resolve(3);
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(15);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  }
  return $httpMock;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="room in rooms">
    <div>{{room.room}}</div>
    <br>
    <div>{{room.plantCount}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of couple of things going wrong,
1. `$scope.plantCount`function should return count.

```
$scope.plantCount = function(room) {
        var url = '/getplantsbyroom/' + room;
        $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
            $scope.count = response;
            return response
        })
    }
});
```

2. Rather than calling function from parent access value return by function as you are already calling it in parent property.
See how directive scope works in [blog](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/)

Here is the solution I tried and its working, I replaced methods with default values.

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.rooms = [{
        Name: "room1",
        PlantsCount: "1"
      }, 
       {
        Name: "room2",
        PlantsCount: "2"
      }];

    $scope.plantCount = function(room) {
      return room.PlantsCount;
    }
  })

.directive("plant", function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        attrcount: "="
      },
      template: '<p >{{attrcount}}</p>' //doesn't display count
    }
  });
```

Can be used like,

```
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="room in rooms">
    <div>{{room.Name}}</div>
    <br>
    <div plant attrcount="plantCount(room)"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
```